# Firebase auth with custom token gives null uid

Tags: firebase, jwt, auth0

I'm using Firebase's `authWithCustomToken` method as part of a delegated auth flow through auth0.

Auth0 gives me a JWT through its [`delegate` call](https://auth0.com/docs/auth-api#post--delegation), which I then pass to [`authWithCustomToken`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithcustomtoken.html). Firebase tells me auth was successful and gives me a value under `authData` but this value has null as its `uid`. AFAIK, my Firebase security rules have to use the UID for restriction, so it seems that something is going wrong.

Here's the `authData` response:

```
{ auth: { fb_id: 'auth0|555afce3f3066cf36f5ebd58' },
expires: 1453234943,
token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2ZyZWVmb3JtZXJzLmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw1NTVhZmNlM2YzMDY2Y2YzNmY1ZWJkNTgiLCJhdWQiOiJQaEpNNzdmVjhVbnl5Rjc3REFKQzdOM1BPRnNoZTRVYSIsImV4cCI6MTQ1MzIzNDk0MywiaWF0IjoxNDUzMTk4OTQzLCJ2IjowLCJkIjp7ImZiX2lkIjoiYXV0aDB8NTU1YWZjZTNmMzA2NmNmMzZmNWViZDU4In0sImF6cCI6InJnZ3VBc1hkT25mY0NTT1FLcTdpU3F2cDRER1ZMQTVUIn0.87DmiUn0TY0G3kpPyiJoK6d-aTKsBNlfHBHbM4R4WMk',
uid: null,
provider: 'custom' }
```

Comment: When you call `authWithCustomToken`, the `auth` variable contains *exactly* the information that was in the JWT. Did you check to ensure there is a `uid` property in the JWT that Auth0 generates? Also note that Firebase security rules don't *require* the presence of a `uid`, it is just very common to have one. But for example,  this blog post talking about auth0 with Firebase doesn't use a `uid`: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-06-05-auth0-guest-blog.html

Comment: Just a quick question for clarification: are you implementing a Firebase/Auth0 connection yourself? If so, perhaps [implementing Firebase as an Auth0 addon](https://auth0.com/docs/server-apis/firebase) might work around your issue?

If not, let me know and I'll gladly look more into your implementation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen -- that's it! I didn't grok that uid is just a convention. For sanity though I've had auth0 bundle that in the JWT now.
@KassandraPerch -- That's what I was doing, you only get a `fb_id` in the JWT by default.

Comment: Great to hear Shaun. I added it as an answer.

Comment: Most likely, Auth0 is working on a very old version of the token generator. Firebase custom auth [token generators](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html#section-rest-token-helper-libraries) now require `uid` in order to create tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `authWithCustomToken()`, the `auth` variable contains exactly the information that was in the JWT. If there is no `auth.uid`, it is probably because Auth0 didn't add one to the token.

Note that Firebase security rules don't *require* the presence of a uid, it is just very common to have one. But for example, this blog post talking about auth0 with Firebase doesn't use a uid: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-06-05-auth0-guest-blog.html